# actual link in source code of angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a 'Read more' on a page where the link is generated through AngularJS.  In source code it is appearing as Angular JS code not as an actual link.

It is troubling in SEO purpose as the crawler of the tool I am using not accepting the AngularJS Code as proper link.

I want to convert the AngularJS code to proper html link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you put your some code which you are using for 'Read more'

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty Sorry, I can not share code.  It is very confidential. Thanks!

Comment: Hey guys, actually the code and view source were all good and correct.  We had to make some changes in the SEO tool, basically we enabled JS in SEO tool and after that it did not reported as an issue.

Thanks for your support!